# Retrieving data from textarea php

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I cannot seem to retrieve the data input into this text area. Also I know this code may not be secure, but I am just beginning with php.

```
echo '<tr><td align=right>Description:</td><td><textarea name=description form=description cols=100 rows=5></textarea></td></tr>';

$descriptionToSend = $("#description").val()
DBSubmit("INSERT INTO Conference (conferenceid,description,submission_due,review_due) VALUES ('".$_POST['conferenceName']."', '" . $descriptionToSend . "','" .$_POST['submitdeadline'] . "','" .$_POST['reviewdeadline']. "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you mixing up jquery with php ?

First, the `<textarea>` should reside in a `<form>`

After the form is submitted to php, you can access the data sent with $_REQUEST['description'] so you would have

```
$descriptionToSend = $_REQUEST['description'];
```

Comment: in my code it is inside of a form. I tried retrieving it earlier by using $_GET['description']

Comment: then show us more code. because the line `$descriptionToSend = $("#description").val()` leads me to think you are mixing jquery with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php $name = 'nick';
     ?>
<form action="Test.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
About Me: <textarea name="about" rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $comment; ?></textarea><br/>
Click Me: <input type="submit" vaule="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Use `$comment` to set text and then just retrieve value using `$_GET['about']` in next page

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$about = $_GET['about'];
echo $about;
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```